# http://localhost:3000/api/posts i am getting COULD NOT GET ANY RESPONSE. using POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, mean

```
    // this is app.js which is the main application file
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var api = require('./routes/api');``
    //var users = require('./routes/users');

    var app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  //  app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/api', api);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            res.status(err.status || 500);
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });


    module.exports = app;
```

and this is api.js which implements the RESTful API.Post is a resource and because of this we will implement a /posts API which will First we'll implement placeholder route handlers for the /posts api within api.js.

var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

```
//api for all posts
router.route('/posts')

    //create a new post
    .post(function(req, res){

        //TODO create a new post in the database
        res.json({message:"TODO create a new post in the database"});
    })

    .get(function(req, res){

        //TODO get all the posts in the database
        res.json({message:"TODO get all the posts in the database"});
    })



module.exports = router;
```

i am getting this on postman

Answer (score 2):

You should be going to

http://localhost:3000/api/posts

Not

http://localhost:3000/routes/api/posts

..

Edit:

I didn't realize you're trying to call

```
req.send
```

Well that is not a method of

```
req (request)
```

You're looking for

```
res (response)
```

And on top of that you're trying to send a json result, not plain text so use

```
res.json
```

Instead of

res.send

Comment: I haven't used postman are you trying to get a json response? Use res.json not req.send @ParijatPandey

Comment: yes @Datsik i am trying to get the json response.Tried res.json too but getting the same result.

Comment: Update your code in your question so i can see @ParijatPandey

Comment: i am following this link https://github.com/hwz/chirp/tree/master/module-3
hope you will get more info here.Updated

Comment: @ParijatPandey have you looked at the node console to see if you're even getting requests or to see if node is throwing errors? Attach a screenshot of postman too

Comment: i ccant attach a screenshot as i should have atleast 10 reputation which i dont have.I am basically new to this so I dont know how to check in the node console.In the browser it is showing GET http://localhost:3000/api/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost:3000/api/posts:1.

Comment: @ParijatPandey connection refused sounds like a port issue, make sure your port 3000 is open, also make sure your node app is running. You should be able to check the node console where you're running npm start

Comment: yes port 3000 is open and my node app is running too but still the same error

Comment: @ParijatPandey have you restarted your program since making those changes??

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you starting the server with `app.listen(3000)`. You merely export the express app.

Or is there a different module that spins up the server?

Comment: yes there is a different module for that .You can find the code in that file here : https://github.com/hwz/chirp/blob/master/chirp/bin/www